# pre processor compare variables

Tags: c++, preprocessor

I have a file A.h and B.h.

FileA.h is:

```
#define AA1 1

#define BB2 2

#define CC3 3
```

FileB.h is:

```
#include <FileA.h>
#define AA 1

#define BB 2

#define CC 3

#if AA != FileA.AA1 //is this the way to call AA1 variable in FileA??
#error "Mismatch variable"
#endif
```

I want to have a compiler error when if the definein fileA.h does not match the value in file FileB.h. Therefore I added a #error.
How would i reference the AA1 deine in FileA.cpp in the if statement in FileB.h?

is this line correct? #if AA != FileA.AA1
how would i call a define in another file in #if preprocessor???

Comment: Macro names are global and cannot be redefined.

Comment: Also, including a `cpp` file isn't usually what you want... You should use headers...

Comment: Macmade: sry it is actually .h, typo, corrected it

Comment: Macmade: how would i solve this problem??

Comment: @Macmade They're not global they're local to the translation unit and you can use `#undef` / `#define` combination to redefine them.

Comment: Captain Obvlious: how do i get the AA variable from FlieA.h to FileB.h??

Comment: If you are following good development practices you don't. This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) so it's probably best you take a step back and rethink your approach. It would help if you edited your post and expanded on why you want or think you need to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. `#define` macros are not member variables in the sense that you are thinking about them at all. If you want FileA and FileB to have similar `#define`s, you have to use naming conventions to differentiate them.

Typically you would prefix your `#define`s with an identifier, such as `#define FILEA_AA 125` and `#define FILEB_AA 300`.

Then you can compare them with preprocessor directives as follows:

```
#if FILEA_AA == FILEB_AA
/* Code goes here */
#endif
```

Comment: how would i reference to variable AA in FileA in FileB??

Comment: @user19871986user19871986 that is what I'm getting at. You can't. #define macros are not member variables in the sense that you are thinking about them at all. If you want FileA and FileB to have similar #defines, you have to use naming conventions to differentiate them.

Comment: Recommend an edit to add that tidbit to the answer. It's important and some poor soul could miss it burred in the comments.

Comment: Treebasher: naming convention ? can u give an example?

Comment: @user19871986user19871986 my post is an example.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with `#define`. `#define`ed identifier is not a variable. `#define` is a simple text replacement performed by the preprocessor before the compiler really gets started.

Simplistically what happens is something like this: Some file includes FileB.h. This effectively pastes FileB.h into the including file, replacing the include statement. Shortly thereafter the preprocessor finds the include of FileA.h and does the same thing: pastes in FileA.h. You wind up with something like:

```
#define AA 1

#define BB 2

#define CC 3

#define AA 1

#define BB 2

#define CC 3

#if AA != FileA.AA //is this the way to call AA1 variable in FileA??
#error "Mismatch variable"
#endif
```

This repeats the definitions. A decent compiler will spit out a warning if they do not match. For example, if I force a mismatch:

```
..\src\main.cpp:9:0: warning: "AA" redefined [enabled by default]
     #define AA 2
 ^
..\src\main.cpp:3:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
     #define AA 1
```

I usually run with warnings treated as errors, so I wouldn't bother going any further. (Side note on why I take this draconian approach: A compiler error means the syntax is bad and the code is not executable. A warning means while the code can be executed it very likely won't do what you intend it to do. If the program's not going to work, why bother building it?)

So how do we get around this?

We take a lesson from the great and mighty Sauron and craft One Header to Rule them all. After all, If the values must be in lock-step, why repeat them? That way lies only madness and bugs. The only downside with this approach is filthy hobbitsies stealing the precious. Doesn't happen all that often.

Common definitions are moved to a header used by other headers. In this model, FileA.h and FileB.h both `#include "coredefs.h"`which contains all of the core definitions like `AA` and its ilk. Since this coredefs.h is included by pretty much everyone, [read up on Include Guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

coredefsh. is:

```
#ifndef COREDEFS_H
#define COREDEFS_H

#define AA1 1

#define BB2 2

#define CC3 3

#endif
```

FileA.h is:

```
#ifndef FILEA_H
#define FILEA_H

#include "coredefs.h"

// other File A stuff here
#endif
```

FileB.h is:

```
#ifndef FILEB_H
#define FILEB_H

#include "coredefs.h"

// other File B stuff here
#endif
```